# Change InputLanguage doen't work WPF

Tags: wpf, input-language

I've problem with OSK in WPF. I change the InputLanauage by InputLanguageManager like this:

```
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(_targetKeyboardWindow, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru"));
```

But it doesn't work. I need to change the actual view of my application (by click back button) and then my changes in InputLanguageManager starts to work. But when I tried to change View from code-behind after I change input language - it does not work.

Moreover, in debugger I can see that after changing language, the current language is still default (previous)

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the solution is trivial .

Instead of:

```
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(_targetKeyboardWindow, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru"));
```

use:

```
InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = new CultureInfo("ru");
```

Best regards.